# Revert a local commit

Tags: git

I am interested in how can I remove a local commit(i.e. a commit which is not pushed to the remote) without loosing the changes contained by it.

What I did : 
- committed my local changes(I never pushed it to the remote)
- reverted that commit
- checked if I still have the changes
After performing all of the above steps I realized that my local changes were lost. I had to revert the revert commit in order to get them back.

My question is : Which is the proper way for removing a local commit without losing the changes included in it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I undo the most recent local commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-local-commits-in-git), i.e: `git reset HEAD~`

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered several times. See: [How do I undo the most recent local commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-local-commits-in-git/6866485#6866485)

What you want to do is `git reset --soft 4817564` where 4817564 is the SHA of the commit you want to revert to.

Answer (score 0):

If we had the commit graph:

```
branch1    A---B---C
```

And we wanted to rollback/revert/ the changes in `C`, but still keep them easily accessible - I would handle this situation as follows:

1. `git checkout branch1` - Switch to the latest `branch1` (currently `C`)
2. `git branch branch2` - Create the branch pointing to the changes
3. `git reset --hard B` - Remove the `C` changes from the branch

To get the final state:

```
branch1    A---B
                \
branch2          C
```

---

I like this approach because it allows me to easily reference the change branch if I need to merge, rebase, or cherry-pick those changes at a later date. Additionally, by keeping it as a branch (as opposed to just writing down the commit Id) I ensure the changes are reachable and thus will never be garbage collected.

NOTE: This approach will work even if the changes are spaced across multiple commits - and have the same benefits